# Mouse pointer not visible/usable in Genymotion virtual machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I've recently installed Genymotion and had it create an android virtual device inside Virtual Box. The virtual machine seems to start OK, but when I click inside the Virtual Box area I get the message:

> You have **clicked the mouse** inside the Virtual Machine display or pressed the **host key**. This will cause the Virtual Machine to **capture** the host mouse pointer ...

I click on **Capture** and the mouse pointer disappears. I'm not able to do anything with the mouse inside the Virtual Machine. Does anyone have a clue on what I could be doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot of the Virtual Machine, emulating an android device:

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592055/mouse-doesnt-work-in-the-guest-os-ubuntu-14-04-2-on-virtual-box-installed-on) related?

Comment: @KNeerajLal It seems to refer to the same issue. I tried disabling mouse integration (as the OP of the post suggest) but that didn't help. I'll check the rest of the answers.

Comment: I don't know if you are using the vm for a particular reason. if it's not the case.


why are you opening the emulator in the vm. you should instead use Genymotion app.

Comment: @humazed I can't believe it was so simple! If you place your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should run the emulator using the genymotion app.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was trying to start the emulator from within the Virtual Box interface. I have used Virtual Box many times in the past for different purposes. So it was a bit of a habit for me to start the machine this way.